# visual c++ undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, identifier

in A.h

```
#pragma once
include "B.h"
class A {
    B* aPtrToB;
}
```

in B.h

```
#pragma once
include "A.h"
class B{
    A* aPtrToA;
}
```

visual c++ says "error C2065: 'A' : undeclared identifier"

any ideas?

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a cyclic inclusion. The `#pragma once` is preventing the infinite inclusion that would result from this, but it means that either `A` won't have the definition of `B` above it or `B` won't have the definition of `A` above it, depending on which ever was compiled first.

The solution is to not `#include` the header files, since you only need a forward declaration to declare a pointer:

```
#pragma once

class B;

class A {
    B* aPtrToB;
};
```

and:

```
#pragma once

class A;

class B {
    A* aPtrToA;
};
```